# change data in a dataframe by a percentage in a list column by column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with some numeric data and I also have an array with some numbers, this array is the change in percentage for each column in the order of the values of the array.

for example, if I have the array

```
percentage_change <- c(10,10,0,-10,-10)


A <- c(100,100,100,100,100)
B <- c(100,100,100,100,100)
C <- c(100,100,100,100,100)
D <- c(100,100,100,100,100)
E <- c(100,100,100,100,100)

data <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, E)
```

what I would need is a piece of code that would change the columns in the "data" dataframe by the percentage of the number in the array

the final result would be like this

```
    A    B   C   D   E
   110 110  100 90  90
   110 110  100 90  90
   110 110  100 90  90
    .   .    .   .   .
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(t(t(data) + t(data) * percentage_change/100))
    A   B   C  D  E
1 110 110 100 90 90
2 110 110 100 90 90
3 110 110 100 90 90
4 110 110 100 90 90
5 110 110 100 90 90
```

Comment: What if `data` isn't all 100? 50 + 10 is a 20% increase for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pmap_dfr` -

```
percentage_change <- percentage_change/100

purrr::pmap_dfr(data, ~{
  x <- c(...) 
  x + x * percentage_change
})

#     A     B     C     D     E
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   110   110   100    90    90
#2   110   110   100    90    90
#3   110   110   100    90    90
#4   110   110   100    90    90
#5   110   110   100    90    90
```

Or in base R -

```
#apply
data[] <- t(apply(data, 1, function(x) x + x * percentage_change))

#Map
data[] <- Map(function(x, y) x + x*y, data, percentage_change)
```